# Lost LVM meta data, but filesystem still works

Tags: lvm, storage-area-network, iscsi, xfs

Here is setup:

- 70TB JBOD as part of a SAN, split into 5 LUNs  (4x15TB and 1x10TB).
- File server running Centos 7 connects to the 5 LUNs via iSCSI, using `iscsiadm`, across two netowrk paths, for a total of 10 paths.
- Use `dm-multipath` to aggregate these iSCSI paths into single devices ie, `/dev/mapper/mpath*`.
- Build physical volumes using `pvcreate` on the above `dm-mutipath` devices.
- Build a single volume group using all physical volumes.
- Build multiple logical volumes to desired capacity.
- Format logical volumes as XFS using `mkfs.xfs`.

Now, there was an issue with the SAN which necessitated maintenance (upgrade of controller firmware) and thus I rebooted the file server to ensure that nothing got screwy when the SAN came back online.

Upon reboot, I was able to reconnent to the SAN and mount the filesystems. They are operating normally.

However, after reboot of the file server, I noticed that the LVM information for these file systems do not appear i.e. `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay`, and `lvdisplay` only report the local disk on the file server.

These VG and LV do appear in `/dev`:

```
/dev/vg_${VG}
/dev/vg_${VG}/${LV1}_lv
/dev/vg_${VG}/${LV2}_lv
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-${VG}-${LV1}_lv
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-${VG}-${LV2}_lv
/dev/mapper/vg_${VG}-${LV1}_lv
/dev/mapper/vg_${VG}-${LV1}_lv
```

And they do appear using `pvs -a` but have zero extents:

```
[root@file-server /]# pvs -a
PV                                     VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/centos/home                                   ---       0     0
/dev/centos/root                                   ---       0     0
/dev/centos/swap                                   ---       0     0
/dev/mapper/mpatha                                 ---       0     0
/dev/mapper/mpathb                                 ---       0     0
/dev/mapper/mpathc                                 ---       0     0
...
/dev/sda                                           ---       0     0
/dev/sda1                                          ---       0     0
/dev/sda2                              centos lvm2 a--  273.80g 4.00m
/dev/sdb                                           ---       0     0
/dev/sdc                                           ---       0     0
/dev/sdd                                           ---       0     0
/dev/sde                                           ---       0     0
...
/dev/vg_${VG1}/${LV1}_lv               ---       0     0
/dev/vg_${VG1}/${LV2}_lv                  ---       0     0
```

They also appear with `dmsetup info -c`:

```
[root@file-server /]# dmsetup info -c
Name                              Maj Min Stat Open Targ Event  UUID
mpathe                            253   6 L--w    1    1      1 mpath-27f3164e4727f3bc5
mpathd                            253   5 L--w    1    1      1 mpath-2b3c12e7d9acc5f25
mpathc                            253   4 L--w    1    1      1 mpath-232eb560378e8ec53
mpathb                            253   7 L--w    1    1      1 mpath-218029135ad1e514a
mpatha                            253   3 L--w    1    1      1 mpath-20123b6d74acce549
vg_${VG}-${LV1}_lv    253  16 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-6DoB20ypbwcGOoRHiX0t8wKAY3oC9BXtSGzQ1wy8fGa9okuQm1NxtPCHnmt0dtO6
vg_${VG}-${LV2}_lv   253  17 L--w    1    3      0 LVM-6DoB20ypbwcGOoRHiX0t8wKAY3oC9BXtmgFlfK9Bilo3IAWxjqwR7dUA8Oq0Fu70
mpathj                            253  15 L--w    1    1      1 mpath-266772bd8af26c781
centos-home                       253   2 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-GAWmujV5zkPn9byt74PY7byRJUWi8UmYSqsQjkt2uTDQ1q5Do38GXYynZhTiLhYw
mpathi                            253  14 L--w    1    1      1 mpath-254a27729bfbfc8c6
mpathh                            253  13 L--w    1    1      1 mpath-2a0ff1a2db7f22f00
mpathg                            253  12 L--w    1    1      1 mpath-27a5ce08413f48f13
mpathf                            253  11 L--w    1    1      1 mpath-2d19e7002c7a41667
centos-swap                       253   1 L--w    2    1      0 LVM-GAWmujV5zkPn9byt74PY7byRJUWi8UmYtA03QjyV1IlWWk9Nz9cHJFKN16SJZ0T5
centos-root                       253   0 L--w    1    1      0 LVM-GAWmujV5zkPn9byt74PY7byRJUWi8UmYCMmaP0envGMf3gk8JhcyoQIQPGmjrL6w
```

How to I re-instate the LVM meta data? It is simply a matter of `vgcfgrestore` as outlined here:

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/mdatarecover.html

I appear to have a backup in `/etc/lvm/backup`.

I hesitate to fiddle with this in case I lose any data on the file systems. Recovery is possible, but not without system downtime and delay.

EDIT: Output from `pvs`, `lvs`, and `vgs` below:

```
[root@dfile-server ~]# pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--  273.80g 4.00m
[root@file-server ~]# lvs
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home centos -wi-ao----  46.57g
  root centos -wi-ao---- 221.64g
  swap centos -wi-ao----   5.59g
[root@file-server ~]# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  centos   1   3   0 wz--n- 273.80g 4.00m
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `lsblk`, `blkid /dev/mapper/mpatha [b] [c] ...` and `mount` ?

Comment: @shodanshok: here are links: http://pastebin.com/DJgXRgks, http://pastebin.com/7FgMZn2v, and http://pastebin.com/pQQGU5mp. I will update post with truncated versions if solution works out.

Comment: @shodanshok: I started looking at the `blkid /dev/sd*` as well and they match what I see in `/etc/lvm/backup/`.

Comment: Ok, the block devices seem ok. Can you add the output of `pvscan -vvv` and `pvs -vvv` ?

Comment: Thanks. Here you go. pvscan: http://pastebin.com/NZ3SyYMv. pvs:  http://pastebin.com/N9Cr5Xbf.

Comment: It seems a `lvmetad` problem, and I suspect it has nothing to do with the SAN upgrade, rather with the reboot. Try to stop `lvmetad` issuing the commands `systemctl stop lvmetad.service; systemctl stop lvmetad.socket` and retry with `pvscan; pvs` (and paste output). If this is not sufficient, can you update the machine (`yum update`) and reboot?

Comment: after `systemctl stop` commands: `pvscan`: http://pastebin.com/H2dtxWLc, `pvs`: http://pastebin.com/fnwPmhHX. Also `(pv|vg|lv)display` show the correct output now. Thank you! If I count upvote you 1000x I would :) Please feel free to post an official answer and I will promptly accept it.

Comment: Before to write the answer, we should re-enable `lvmetad`. Please issue `pvscan --cache` and re-enable `lvmetad` with `systemctl start lvmetad.service; system to start lvmetad.socket; pvscan --cache`. Finally run `pvs` and check if the volumes continue to be recognized.

Comment: Seems to work: http://pastebin.com/S7Cqx9p8.

Comment: Ok, I'll post the answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As diagnosed in the comments, the problem had nothing to do with the SAN upgrade, rather with `lvmetad` daemon returning stale/wrong information.

This was confirmed by stopping `lvmetad` (`systemctl stop lvmetad.service; systemctl stop lvmetad.socket`) and by issuing `pvs` which, directly analyzing the block devices, return correct information.

The permanent fix was to update `lvmetad` cache, by informing it that something changed. This was accomplished running `pvscan --cache`, re-enabling `lvmetad` (`systemctl start lvmetad.service; systemctl start lvmetad.socket`) and finally running another `pvscan --cache`.

After that, normal `pvs` (with `lvmetad` active) returned correct data.